# MYSQL delete from exception

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So i have a cron job that deletes dowload tokens every 24H:

```
$db->query('DELETE FROM download_token WHERE expiry < :expiry', array('expiry' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')));
```

But i don't want mysql to delete the download token from a user id in this case user id 29 it can delete everything else but not the token of user id 29

How can i do this? What about this?: `$db->query('DELETE FROM download_token WHERE user_id IS NOT '29' AND expiry < :expiry', array('expiry' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')));`

The user_id's are saved in the same table.

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Just `AND`, not `AND WHERE`, and `!=` should be find for testing the user_id. So `WHERE user_id != 29 AND expiry < :expiry...`.

Comment: Like this: $db->query('DELETE FROM download_token WHERE user_id != 29 AND expiry < :expiry', array('expiry' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')));  ?

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to add another condition to your query:

```
$db->query(
  'DELETE FROM download_token WHERE expiry < :expiry AND user_id != :user_id',
  array('expiry' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), 'user_id' => 29)
);
```

The `IS NOT` clause is reserved for comparing values to `NULL` since that's an odd type of value: `NULL != NULL` and `NULL = NULL` both return `NULL`.

Comment: @BrianHeldens Slap the big green checkmark on there if you're confident that's the right answer. It helps others find the solution if they have a similar problem.